# Spring - Using Value annotation to read from the local config file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, nullpointerexception

I am trying to use the Value annotation in Spring to read from the local application.yaml file I put in the same package as my main and unit test class. I have a simple class with the method that gets the config value:

```
public class EmailValidator {

    String getConfigValue(configurationProvider1 configurationReader, String configName) {
        String value = null;
        ConfigurationProvider reader;
        try {
            reader = configurationReader.configurationProvider();
            value = reader.getProperty(configName, String.class);
            //the `reader` above is null when I run the test, so I get Null Pointer Exception on this line
            if (value == null) {
                LOGGER.warn("The configuration for " + configName + " cannot be found.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

And I have a configuration provider class which sets the configuration reader so that my class above can make use of it to read the application.yaml file:

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@NoArgsConstructor
@ComponentScan
public class configurationProvider1 {

        @Value("${configFilesPath:./domain/application.properties}")//Not really sure if this is the right way of locating my configuration file
        @Getter
        private String filePath;

        @Bean
        public ConfigurationProvider configurationProvider() throws FileNotFoundException {
            if (!Paths.get(this.filePath).toFile().exists()) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Configuration file doesn't exist: " + this.filePath);
            }

            ConfigFilesProvider configFilesProvider =
                    () -> Collections.singletonList(Paths.get(filePath).toAbsolutePath());
            ConfigurationSource source = new FilesConfigurationSource(configFilesProvider);
            Environment environment = new ImmutableEnvironment(this.filePath);

            return new ConfigurationProviderBuilder()
                    .withConfigurationSource(source)
                    .withEnvironment(environment)
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

As commented above, I'm not sure if `@Value("${configFilesPath:./domain/application.properties}")` is a right way of locating my local application.properties file (The classes are in the same package called `domain` but the config file is not in the resources folder since this is a service layer. So it is just right under the `domain` package).

And when I try to test my getConfigValue method in my first class, I get NPE (I assume its because the configurationReader I am passing in as a parameter to getConfigValue method is null):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class EmailValidatorTest {

    @MockBean
    private configurationProvider1 configurationReader = mock(configurationProvider1.class);

    @Autowired
    private DefaultEmailValidator validator;//maybe I should inject the dependency somewhere?

    @Test
    public void simple(){
        String a = validator.getConfigValue(configurationReader,"mail.subject.max.length");
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

I am not sure if my class is actually reading the config value from the config file at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. The code is updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**@Value**

> Spring’s @Value annotation provides a convenient way to inject property values into components, not to provide the properties file path

**@PropertySource** Use **@PropertySource** for that [Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)

> Annotation providing a convenient and declarative mechanism for adding a PropertySource to Spring's Environment. To be used in conjunction with `@Configuration` classes
>
> Given a file app.properties containing the key/value pair `testbean.name=myTestBean`, the following `@Configuration` class uses `@PropertySourc`e to contribute `app.properties` to the Environment's set of PropertySources.

**Example**

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySource("classpath:/com/myco/app.properties")
 public class AppConfig {

 @Autowired
 Environment env;

 @Bean
 public TestBean testBean() {
     TestBean testBean = new TestBean();
     testBean.setName(env.getProperty("testbean.name"));
     return testBean;
   }
 }
```

[24.7.4 YAML Shortcomings](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings)

> YAML files cannot be loaded by using the `@PropertySource` annotation. So, in the case that you need to load values that way, **you need to use a properties file.**

**Coming to Test case** you should not create new instance of `DefaultEmailValidator` you need to use `@SpringBootTest`

**@SpringBootTest** [Example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing)

> The `@SpringBootTest` annotation can be used when we need to bootstrap the entire container. The annotation works by creating the ApplicationContext that will be utilized in our tests.

**RunWith(SpringRunner.class)**

> @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) is used to provide a bridge between Spring Boot test features and JUnit. Whenever we are using any Spring Boot testing features in out JUnit tests, this annotation will be required.

**@MockBean**

> Another interesting thing here is the use of @MockBean. It creates a Mock

**EmailValidatorTest**

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @SpringBootTest
 public class EmailValidatorTest {

@MockBean
private configurationProvider1 configurationReader;

@Autowire
private DefaultEmailValidator validator

@Test
public void testGetConfigValue(){
    String a = validator.getConfigValue(configurationReader,"mail.subject.max.length");
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply :) I tried the above and still getting NPE for the line `String a = validator.getConfigValue(configurationReader,"mail.subject.max.length");`. And I have created the `application.properties` file and put it under the `domain` folder and also put the `@Value("${configFilesPath:./domain/application.properties}")` above the @Getter for the filePath. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: let me know if you want me to open another ticket for the NPE :)